# How to host Apache SuperSet on an Amazon EC2 intance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-superset

I am trying to host an Apache superset server on an Amazon EC2 instance. Whenever i host it from a standalone ssh, the moment i close the terminal from my laptop, the superset server shuts down..Is there a way i can host SuperSet server on Amazon EC2 instance so that it is online always ?

Comment: Run it in `screen` or `tmux` for testing. For more permanent solution setup `systemd` unit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it using `nohup superset <options> &`. Then even after you close the terminal, it continues to run. 
Stopping it should require `kill` the process using PID, which can be found using `grep`.